# How to make an IE addon/extension in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ieaddon

I need to create a simple IE addon, and trying to figure out how to do that in JavaScript. So far I saw a bunch of .NET examples on MSDN, and I've also seen the FireBreath project (which is kinda cool but it's in C++), but nothing in pure JavaScript.

Is there a way at all to make an extension for IE kinda the same way like we do it for FF/Chrome/Opera?

Thanks.

PS: I don't need any UI components, all I need is to track a page-load and alter a bit the HTML page, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way at all to make an extension for IE kinda the same way like we do it for FF/Chrome/Opera?

In short, no. Sorry. IE extensions need to be compiled, so you can't write them in a scripted language.

You should be able to write it in your choice of .NET language, but Javascript isn't going to be in that list.

Comment: yup, that's what I've figured.

there is another option, to run javascript via greasemonkey, but it again will require the user to install gm4ie or a similar extension first

Comment: Sounds nice, but the FAQ is not clear how the licensing costs when one wants to monetize with it. One would need to call to find that price.

Answer (score 6):

You can try http://kangoextensions.com/ or http://crossrider.com/ both provide a cross browser extensions support which developed in JavaScript

Comment: kango is not active for last few months.

Answer (score 2):

[Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) is across-browser development framework design specifically for what you need and asked for. [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) was built with Javascript in mind and has buit-in support for jQuery as well.

Here are some of the benefits of using Crossrider:

1. Build cross-browser extensions with only javascript code and one API
2. Supports Chrome, Firefox, Safari and most importantly Internet Explorer!
3. Fully customized Windows Installer which can be install on all browse from one EXE and can also be defined as a SILENT installer.
4. Hosted installation pages and Installation Widget if you wish to install user to your own    website

But as the most powerful thing about Crossrider is the ability for a "regular" javascript developer to build cross-browser exetnsions from scratch that will work on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and obviously Interner Explorer.

(Disclosure: I am a Crossrider employee)

Comment: Any alternative of crossrider to build IE extensions in javascript ? As crossrider is shutting down for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it may be possible to do so without 3rd party tools. But the article is limited to context menu items. Other articles in the same category may be of some use. Although, they are marked as deprecated, so for how long they'll be useful is not clear.